# Most efficient way to replace every possible combination of up to N items in a tuple in Python?

Tags: python

If I have a tuple of a generic length. Given a specific N, what is the most efficient way to create every single possible combination of the tuple where the token `""` replaces up to N items in the tuple?

For example, non efficient way of doing this

```
 def create_feature_graph(l,N):
     all_combinations = list(set(product(*zip(l, repeat('')))))
     all_combinations = [x for x in all_combinations if x.count('') <= N]
     return all_combinations

l = ('A','B','C')
print(create_feature_graph(l,1))
[('A','B','C'),('','B','C'),('A','','C'),('A','B','')]
```

The current implementation first creates the following list

```
[('A','B','C'),('','B','C'),('A','','C'),('A','B',''),('','','C'),('',B,''),('A','',''),('','','')]
```

Before filtering for every item which consists of up to N occurences of `""`, which is not very efficient for large lists.

What would be a smart and more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: How about [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

Comment: Perhaps, but I still want to keep the original length of the tuple, combinations would not do this.

Comment: The second line where you fully expand the list-comprehension `all_combinations = [x for x in all_combinations ...]` is a really bad idea, it'll eat up memory. You don't need to do that. Really you only want to generate a tuple of binary digits, then element-wise logical-and it with your tuple of letters.

Comment: That's why I am asking this question, since my current solution is not good.

Comment: Here, **N is the maximum number of binary bits allowed to be zero**. And of course since you have K=3 letters, you need to count up to **2^K -1**

Answer (score 0):

Binaries! What you are looking for is basically: a letter is either replaced(1) or not (0).

All possible replacements give you 2^N of possible results, so lets iterate over them and replace each letter of input, where corresponding binary index is 1.

```
def replacements(data, N = 0):
    for i in range(N or 2 ** len(data)):
        bin_str = str(bin(i))[2:].zfill(len(data)) # form a string representing binary with prepended zeros
        yield tuple(letter if not int(bin_i) else '' for bin_i, letter in zip(bin_str, data))
```

Test:

```
>>> list(replacements(tuple('abc')))
>>> [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', ''), ('a', '', 'c'), ('a', '', ''), ('', 'b', 'c'), ('', 'b', ''), ('', '', 'c'), ('', '', '')]
```

Comment: How do I specifiy N here then? I don't want to generate all the combinations, but only up to N.

Comment: @kspr just limit `range` to N if it is specified. I've updated the answer

Comment: No, N is the maximum number of binary bits allowed to be zero. K=3 is the number of letters, hence we need to count up to 2^K -1.

Comment: @smci It is not. Since OP's expected result includes `('A', 'B', 'C')` and `('', '', '')` - that is exactly from `b000` to `b111` inclusively, which is `2 ** N` and not `2 ** N - 1`

Comment: @go2nirvana I think you misunderstood the last part, I wanted to avoid having to include every single combination. You can see the expected output in the print statement of the first block of code in the question.

Comment: @go2nirvana: ok but my point you're confusing K=3 with N, the maximum number of zero bits. Your "N" is actually "K".

Comment: @kspr Oh, i see now. Then `itertools` it is.

Comment: @smci There is `2 ** N` permutations, but indexing starts from `0` and goes up to `2 ** N - 1`. I think we can agree on that

Comment: Is it possible to modify your code to generate what I am needing?